# Increase Speed of car in Box2D

Tags: box2d

I am making a racing game in which I a using Box2d. I made a car with Wheel Joint. But I am unable to increase the speed of car with time/distance.

When I am increasing MaxTorque then it car moving continuously in the air.
When I am increasing Motor Speed, it cause increase the speed of car but after certain value there is no impact on speed of car

Comment: Maybe this? http://www.iforce2d.net/b2dtut/gotchas#speedlimit There are also limits on how fast a body can rotate. Are you defining sizes in pixels, or meters?

Comment: all the body size define in the box2d units